# How to redirect to another action in Struts in given time?

Tags: java, struts2

For example, once an action has been called I want it to redirect to another action in 5 seconds. Is it possible?

```
    <action name="proceedupdateaccount" class="accountAction" method="updateAccount">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">update-message</result>
        <result name="input">/accountupdateform.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="update-message">
        <result>/message.jsp</result>
        <!-- in 5 seconds this action should redirect to logout action -->
    </action>

    <action name="logout">
        <result type="redirect">/j_spring_security_logout</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: yes suspend it for 5 sec, then redirect.

Comment: Could you please show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply redirect them from the first action to another action using the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" >` code on the first action's result, like this:

In the `message.jsp`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=logout">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Roman, but I think redirecting on client-side is not really good, isn't it? I think the redirection has to be on server side

Comment: Please add your comment to the question. Redirection is always done on the client. Also elaborate how redirection has to be on server side.

Comment: That's why I am asking, I thought there's a way to do the redirection on the server side. Thank you anyway.