# Struts 2 redirecting too much when sent to online server

Tags: java, struts2

First thing I want to apologize for my English.
I have a Java EE app which is running on a remote server.
I have a link in it, lets say it is 'domain:port/MyApp/module'.
The problem is when I run the source code on my localhost Apache tomcat, this link works perfectly, redirecting to a struts action.

E.g: localhost:8090/MyApp/module/ => localhost:8090/MyApp/module/dashboard

But when it's on the remote server, it enter a loop of redirection.

E.g: myserverdomain:8085/MyApp/module/ => myserverdomain:8085/MyApp/module/dashboard => myserverdomain:8085/MyApp/module/ => myserverdomain:8085/MyApp/module/dashboard => ...

My action in struts.xml

```
<action name="/{direction}" class="mg.itu.gamela.action.BaseAction" method="redirectService">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">${pageRedirect}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Linked to:

```
package mg.itu.gamela.action;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import mg.itu.gamela.service.BaseService;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.apache.struts2.util.ServletContextAware;

public class BaseAction implements ServletContextAware, SessionAware {
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

private BaseService baseService;
private ServletContext servletContext;
private Map<String, Object> session;
private String error;
public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String ERROR = "error";

private Exception exception;

public Exception getException() {
    return exception;
}

public void setException(Exception exception) {
    this.exception = exception;
}

public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    return servletContext;
}

public BaseService getBaseService() {
    return baseService;
}

public void setBaseService(BaseService baseService) {
    this.baseService = baseService;
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext sc) {
    this.servletContext = sc;
}

public Map<String, Object> getSession() {
    return session;
}

@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session = session;
}

String direction;
String pageRedirect;

public String getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(String direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}


public String getPageRedirect() {
    return pageRedirect;
}

public void setPageRedirect(String pageRedirect) {
    this.pageRedirect = pageRedirect;
}

public String redirectService(){
    System.out.println("BaseAction.getDirection: " + getDirection());
    try {
        getBaseService().redirect(getDirection(), this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

And in getBaseService().redirect():

```
public void redirect(String direction,BaseAction baseAction) throws Exception{
    String pageRedirect = direction;
    switch(direction){
        case "prescolaire":
            baseAction.setPageRedirect(pageRedirect + "/dashboard");
            break;
        case "alphabetisation":
            baseAction.setPageRedirect(pageRedirect + "/rediriger?pageRedirection=dashboard");
            break;
        case "education":
            User user = (User)baseAction.getSession().get("user");
            if(user.getIdProfil() != ProtectionEducationInclusive.ID_ADMIN && user.getIdProfil() != ProtectionEducationInclusive.ID_SUPER_ADMIN){
                baseAction.setPageRedirect("rediriger?pageRedirection=dashboard_utilisateur");
            }else{
                baseAction.setPageRedirect("rediriger?pageRedirection=dashboard_admin");
            }

            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Redirect to => " + baseAction.getPageRedirect());
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without code...

Comment: How can i send my code?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: you should remove the code from jsp that redirects.

Comment: @RomanC >  don't think there's code that redirect

Comment: What do you think @BaliakaIriana? The code redirects to the action that [redirects infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28266871/573032). Remove the action that redirects.